# Increase number of recent files in Mint start menu

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

The Cinnamon start menu only shows up to 20 items under "Recent Files", how do I increase this limit?

I want to do this because typing a search term into the start menu search bar only considers these 20 items, so it is often unable to find the file I'm looking for.

Further info:

- searching for "recent" in `dconf-editor` did not bring up any relevant settings
- `nemo` (file manager) shows way more items in its "Recent" list (for me it's currently 586, this seems to be limited to exactly 1 month)